# If string contains substring then gather entire string up till "space" delimeter

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have to search through an entire SQL stored procedure for certain strings.  Each line in the procedure has been entered into an array location in an array.  What I need to do is search each entry in the array for a certain substring, in this case I want to search for "EXEC SP_MYSP_".  (This is an example of how all stored procedures are prefixed.)  If the string contains "EXEC SP_MYSP_" then I want to increment a counter (which is very easy to do) but I also want to add the stored procedure name to a list.  Is there a way do read the rest of the stored procedure name and stop reading once I hit a space delimiter?  If anyone could provide some advice that would be greatly appreciated!

The code is fairly simple but I'll add it in case it helps anyone see what I was trying to explain above.

```
if (stringValue.Contains("EXEC SP_MYSP_"))
{
    count++;

    //Get the entire stored procedure name.
}
```

Comment: What does `stringValue` actually contain?

Comment: The stringValue is the current string I am viewing.  I split the entire stored procedure on NewLines and place each line of text into an array.  For each line of text, I do the statement that I entered above.

Comment: It would help to show an example or at least the format of the line that contains the string you're matching. At the moment we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

private Regex pattern = new Regex(@"EXEC SP_MYSP_([^\s]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

private bool TryMatchName(string input, out string name)
{
    var match = pattern.Match(input);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        name = match.Groups[1].Value;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        name = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call this method as follows:

```
const string input = "EXEC SP_MYSP_FOO 1, 2, 3;";
string name;
bool nameFound = TryMatchName(input, out name);
```

The regular expression `EXEC SP_MYSP_([^\s]+)` has the following meaning:

- match the literal substring `EXEC SP_MYSP_`,
- followed by one or more (`+`) characters that are not (`[^…]`) any whitespace character (`\s`),
- and capture that part of the input in a group (`(…)`) so that can be extracted using `match.Groups`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I started to do it a different way by taking the line and putting each word into a new array.  I'm not super familiar on how REGEX works but what you have above helps me out!

Comment: @TheJavaLearner: I added a brief explanation of the regex. Hopefully it makes it a little clearer what's going on inside that method.

Comment: It does! Thank you for the explanation.